# Jquery Calculation of width and height of image from image URL

Tags: jquery, image

I am trying to find out an image's width and height from the Address/URL of the image using javascript and jquery.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 11):

To do it without anything in the body, try the following:

```
var imgURL = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f77ef279d6b33bc09ce5422049dd9e37?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';
var img = $('<img src="'+imgURL+'"/>').load(function(){
    console.log(this.width + ' x ' + this.height);
});
```

Comment: does this download the picture whole to get it size ? 
or gets size without downloading image (assume its 4mb ) ?

Comment: It doesn't *display* the picture but it does have to download the whole image to get its size.

Comment: its not good for to download it over and over again. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="link/to/image.gif" id="imageid" />
<script>
$("img").load(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
});
</script>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/004e8/1)

Comment: i know this sir.. but i cant use id for image.. as i dont have much knowledge about jquery and i've to make some changes in existing jquery code downloaded from a web in which a function takes an image url and then shows it in a div. plz help

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to add id to your image? If you want to take image's width & height, you'll have to append it to the DOM first.

Comment: and where is your problem exactly?

Comment: that's the url after clicking on thumbnail.. i'm showing it in an alert box

Comment: now it did. you're alerting URL to image. just put that image into hidden img tag, wait for it to load and do whatever you want to do with height/width as stated above

Comment: actually sir, i'd like to show large images with their actual width and height that is shown after clicking on thumbnails but now its showing with pre-defined image width and height

Comment: $('#largephoto').css({'width':'100%', 'height':'100%'});

Comment: its not working you can check it out that first image is repeating its width

Answer (score 1):

and to be completely sure: add an onload callback on your image

```
<img src="link/to/image.gif" id="imageid" />
<script>
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
img.onload = function() {
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
}
</script>
```

UPDATE:

```
Comment #1] Okay just tried to be nice?
```

If you want to do it without adding anything the the actually DOM tree:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "link/to/image.gif";
image.onload = function() {
    var width = image.clientWidth;
    var height = image.clientHeight;
};
```

Standalone JS no framework solution.